# Retrieving scope in directive via controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose i have a directive as follow:
1) How can i accesss data1 and data2 value in controller of my view?? 
2) Is it possible that i have a return `modelValue` in object form, eg: `form.inputData.data1` and `form.inputData.data2`

```
.directive('splitValue', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                if (modelValue.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
                    scope.data1 = modelValue.split(',')[0];
                    scope.data2 = modelValue.split(',')[1];
                }

                return modelValue;
            })
        }
    }
});

<input type="text" ng-model="form.inputData" split-value>
```

Comment: check my asnwer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> - **demo** : http://so.devilmaycode.it/retrieving-scope-in-directive-via-controller/

```
  var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

    myModule.controller("myController", function($scope) {

      $scope.elementToSplit1 = {
        inputVal: 'comma,separeted',
        data1: '',
        data2: '',
      };

      $scope.elementToSplit2 = {
        inputVal: 'comma,separeted',
        data1: '',
        data2: '',
      };

      // FOR TESTS to see if data is changing or not
      $scope.$watchCollection("elementToSplit1", function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("elementToSplit1", $scope.elementToSplit1.data1, $scope.elementToSplit1.data2)
      });

      // FOR TESTS to see if data is changing or not
      $scope.$watchCollection("elementToSplit2", function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("elementToSplit2", $scope.elementToSplit2.data1, $scope.elementToSplit2.data2)
      });

    });

    myModule.directive('splitValue', function() {
      return {
        template: function(element, attrs) {
          var currentModel = attrs.ngModel;
          var template = '<div class="input-group">' + '<span class="input-group-addon">{{' + currentModel + '.data1}}</span>' + '<span class="input-group-addon">{{' + currentModel + '.data2}}</span>' + '<input type="text" name="' + currentModel + '" class="form-control" ng-model="' + currentModel + '.inputVal">' + '</div>';
          return template;
        },
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          var currentModel = attrs.ngModel;
          scope.$watchCollection(attrs.ngModel + '.inputVal', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
              var splitStr = newValue.split(',');
              scope[currentModel].data1 = splitStr[0];
              scope[currentModel].data2 = splitStr[1];
            } else {
              scope[currentModel].data1 = '';
              scope[currentModel].data2 = '';
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

---

```
<split-value ng-model="elementToSplit1"></split-value>
   <br>
<split-value ng-model="elementToSplit2"></split-value>
```

---

## explanation (?):

a fast answer to your question would be to use `$parent` to set `data1` and `data2` back to it's parent `$scope`, this because your directive is defining it's own `scope`. so `scope.$parent.data1 = modelValue.split(',')[0];` will work.

although this method maybe fine if you have one element, but as soon as you have more, you'll notice that it make no sense to have lot's of directives with hard coded `data1, data2` etc.. inside it; even though you could have used a simple `$watch` in your controller to achieve the same result without using directive.

instead, make sense to have one directive to reuse each time you need it, so, my approach is to not set a new scope, but use the one we already have; then, since `data1` and `data2` belonging to the main input model i have created a template to hold them all.

hope this helped. ;-)